# phpmyadmin/CSV(Excel) Problems

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I have an excel workbook where the .csv file is outputted with quotes with this vba code:

```
 'Set up Delimiters
DELIMITER = ","
QUOTE = """"

 'Set up file to save, ask user for name
GetFileName = InputBox("Enter Name for semi-colon delimited file: (Do not enter file extension)", "FILENAME")
  'CurrentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
 PathtoUse = "C:\Users\David\Desktop\"
 FileNametoUse = PathtoUse & GetFileName & ".csv"

 'Find cells to cycle through
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With

 'Assign a handle to next file#
FileNum = FreeFile

 'Open and write to file named above
Open FileNametoUse For Output As #FileNum

 'Cycle through rows and cols
For Each CurrentRow In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    With CurrentRow 'Now cycle through each cell in the row
        For Each CurrentCell In Range(.Cells, Cells(.Row, LastCol))
             'If the cell contains Non-Numeric (IsNumeric=False) then put quotes around the info
            If IsNumeric(CurrentCell.Text) = False Then
                CellData = QUOTE & CurrentCell.Text & QUOTE
            Else 'The cell contains numeric, use contents as is
                CellData = CurrentCell.Text
            End If
             'as the code cycles, keep adding each col info to string
            LineOutput = LineOutput & DELIMITER & CellData
        Next CurrentCell

         'Remove the first 2 chars in the line (since the delimiter is put in first)
        LineOutput = Mid(LineOutput, 2)
         'Print the line to the file
        Print #FileNum, LineOutput
          'Clear out the variable
        LineOutput = Empty
    End With
Next CurrentRow

 'Close the file
Close #FileNum
```

This outputs the file correctly for example:

```
"FirstName","Surname","YBC","BTBA","JTE","EnteringAverage","DOB","Game1","Game2","Game3","Game4","Game5","Game6","Game7","Game8","IndividualTotal","Average","TeamTotal"
"David","Passmore","Bowlplex Poole",116016,193,179,"05/08/1994",203,254,211,195,187,184,200,267,1701,212.63,3178
"Callum","Bailey","Bowlplex Poole",016015,185,189,"30/05/1996",175,145,195,117,201,265,221,158,1477,184.63,3178
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Firstly I want to know how to remove all the blank cells, and secondly when I input this into phpMyAdmin it all works BUT it misses out the first column and it inputs the column names which I don't want, so I want it to input all the first name column and then I want it to miss out the column names.

My server's phpmyadmin version is 2.6.4 (I know its old but I can't do anything about that)

But is also does this on my local server which is version 3.3.9

**UPDATE**

I've fixed the first column issue by just moving the file one column to the right so that's fixed but the other two problems still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change your vba here:

```
 'Set up Delimiters 
DELIMITER = "," 
QUOTE = """"
```

To this:

```
'Set up Delimiters
DELIMITER = ";"
QUOTE = """"
```

Because phpMyAdmin defaults to ; as the separator.

In answser to your second point you could use this vba code to remove blank cells:

```
Sub MacroNAME()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("sheetname").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Save"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("sheetname").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 14.25
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 14.25
    **Code Used above here**
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 0.1
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("sheetname").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 10.5
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 14.25
    Sheets("Save").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("sheetname").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Save").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This will clear the column headings provided they are it the first row.

You can apply this to a button and it should work.